# Can I put music files on an iPod without iTunes?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, windows, ipod, data-transfer

I can't find any definitive info on this and I need to know for sure before I purchase one.

I *hate* iTunes with a burning passion, but I like iPods and I have a whole lot of music on my PC.

How can I move music from a Windows computer to iOS without using iTunes?

Comment: Side-stepping your question a bit.. are you planning to switch to a mac at any point soon? iTunes on mac is a very different experience thank iTunes on PC. I concur with the "hate" comment!

Comment: I was not planning on it. I did a 1 year stint with Mac and ultimately accepted that I am just a Windows person.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard that happen before! Usually it's a 'never look back' situation. Unless you tried it back in the OS9 days when it was terrible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search for "iTunes alternatives" returns a lot of results. For example: http://www.copytrans.net/copytransmanager.php

Answer (score -1):

use MediaMonkey.com :p you can manage everything from there

Answer (score -1):

- Once you plug in your iPod click on your iPod in the top right on iTunes.
- From there scroll down to options and once you see Manually **"Manage Music and Videos"** tick that.
- Then click Sync in the bottom right.
- To manually add music just select the songs and drag them over to your device.
- I'm assuming you have the newest version of iTunes so it may be easier to go **View > Show Sidebar** (then it will look more like the older version and easier to manage)